# Порядок слів у дієсловах давноминулого часу. ("Була ходила" чи "ходила була"?)

Tags: граматика, дієслова, дієвідмінювання, минулий-час

Чи є якась різниця у вживанні форм давноминулого часу дієслів: "була ходила" чи "ходила була"?

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81) наводить обидва варіанти як коректні приклади вживання цього часу, але у розмовній мові мені допоки здебільшого зустрічався перший варіант.

Comment: Дуже цікаво, що перший. Я стикався з відразою до першого варіанту й нормальним сприйняттям другого, тому перевчився на другий варіант.

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, цікаво, у мене в родині дідусь (з Криворіжжя) використовує завжди перший варіант.

Comment: Назва питання не передає суть питання, виникає враження, що питання про вживання давноминулого часу взагалі (а це питання обговорюється [тут](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/384/)) Варто перейменувати його якось, щоб було зрозуміло, що питання саме про "була ходила" vs "ходила була". Пропозиція від Sasha: «Про порядок слів у давноминулому часі (в сучасній українській мові)» Я б взагалі очевидно назвав: «Чи є різниця між "була ходила" і "ходила була"? (давноминулий час)»

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, слушне зауваження, перейменувала.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В [правописі](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par80p9) написано тільки оце:

"Давноминулий час дієслова складається з форм минулого часу цього дієслова та відповідних форм минулого часу допоміжного дієслова бути: ходив був, ходила була, ходили були."

В тому ж [правописі](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par82) бачимо таке:

"...він би це давно був зробив."

В літературній українській мові є і перший, і другий спосіб творення давноминулого часу. У [вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81) наводять 5 прикладів використання з української художньої літератури, і серед них є і перший, і другий. [Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53396/33233.html) також наводить декілька прикладів, серед яких є обидва способи.

В розмовній українській (як бачите і з коментарів) так само: залежить від звички конкретної людини і милозвучності в кожному конкретному випадку.