# Коли вживати давноминулий час?

Tags: граматика, дієслова, дієвідмінювання, минулий-час

Коли слід вживати давноминулий час («Я *був сказав* йому про це, та потім довго вибачався.»)? Чи його вживання є обов’язковим в сучасній літературній українській мові? Чи вживається ця часова форма лише на позначення дії, яка передувала иншій дії, або й на позначення просто дуже давньої дії?

Яким чином ця часова форма пов’язана з російською «было сказал», як тут: «Я было пошёл туда, но потом вернулся»?

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, я тут повидаляв свої коментарі (з часом видалю і цей).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Об'єктивно

Згідно з ["Як ми говоримо"](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/davnomynulyj-chas-opysova-forma-z-slovamy-bulo-buvalo) одне з вживань давноминулого часу цілковито відповідає Past Perfect в англійській: тобто одна дія перед іншою. Також використовується, коли дію перервано (тобто так само, як у наведеній вами російській фразі).

Давноминулий час, безперечно, не обов'язковий: є низка інших методів передати це, наприклад, словами "раніше", "перед тим" тощо.

Щодо дуже давньої дії, саме це, напевно, є одним з незмінних використань давноминулого часу: початок казок. Казки традиційно починаються з "Жили-були дід та баба (чи хтось інший)...", що й означає "дуже дуже давно".

#### Суб'єктивно

На превеликий жаль, давноминулий час вживається вкрай рідко. Багато хто навіть не знає про його існування, тобто вас можуть навіть не зрозуміти. Лише окремі письменники та перекладачі намагаються його відродити. Я один з таких перекладачів.

Особливо при перекладах з англійської подеколи вкрай зручно передавати [Past Perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_(grammar)) саме давноминулим часом. Усі ці додаткові "раніше", "перед тим", "того дня" роблять фразу неоковирною, і ти заздриш англійській, що там є Past Perfect... І тоді ставиш давноминулий час. :)

Я стикався з несприйняттям давноминолого часу, проте, буквально за тиждень співпраці люди (добре, таких наразі лише двоє, але це тенденція!) самі починали ним користуватися, бо він зручний.

Comment: Є місцевості в Україні, де давньоминулий час вельми поширений у повсякденній розмові. Наприклад, мій батько з Рогатинщини. Там в окремих селах на Опіллі неймовірно часто його використовують. Мені після літніх канікул, проведених у селі, завжди було важко викорінювати надмірне вживання цього часу у моєму мовленні.